# Is Screen Mirroring a feature of the hardware or the software?

Tags: wifi-direct, screencast, miracast

I have a Samsung Galaxy J7 Max running Android Nougat from Samsung. It seems that it does not support screen mirroring but supports Wifi Direct.

I want to know that those phone that do support screen mirroring like the Samsung Galaxy A3, do they have special hardware in them, or is it just enabled in that build of the kernel ?

In short, for screen mirroring do you need extra hardware or just need to enable it in the kernel/OS ?

Answer (score 6):

Both.

Just a brief description of how it works:

At the core of this technology is the Wi-Fi Direct™ standard, which allows for point-to-point connections between devices without the use of a router. From there, Miracast adds a vendor-neutral wrapper that originally supported the streaming of up to 1080p video and 5.1 surround sound. It uses this variation of this technology to allow the output of audio and video.

> For the device whose screen you want to mirror, support for Miracast
>   requires three things: **wireless chipset support**, **operating
>   system support**, and **driver support**. If your device doesn’t meet
>   all three of these requirements then you’ll have to buy a Miracast
>   adapter and upgrade your operating system.

Users can wirelessly mirror the display of their Miracast-certified® phone, tablet, or PC to any Miracast-capable receiver

Android supported Miracast, in Android 4.2 (Jellybean) and Android 5 (Lollipop).

> On 29 October 2012, Google announced that Android version 4.2+ (from
>   updated version of Jelly Bean) are supporting the Miracast wireless
>   display standard, and by default have it integrated.

However, Google **dropped** native Miracast support in Android 6 (Marshmallow) and later, so to mirror the display from a newer Android phone or tablet, you’ll need to do so via Chromecast.

In the case that it is disabled but compatible for a particular Android device, you could edit the `build.prop` file in the following line:

`persist.debug.wfd.enable=1`

Using a root explorer navigate to your `build.prop` file located at 
`/system/build.prop`

Check if the option is visible in Settings > Display > Cast Screen > Menu > Enable Wireless Display.

> Devices that are Miracast-certified® can communicate with each other,
>   regardless of manufacturer.Both devices (the sender and the receiver)
>   need to be **Miracast certified®** for the technology to work.
>   However, to stream music and movies to a non-certified device Miracast
>   adapters are available that plug into HDMI or USB ports.

The [Wi-Fi Alliance](http://www.wi-fi.org/product-finder-results?certifications=46&items=30) has an official list of all Miracast source devices.

There is some evidence however suggesting one can use software based screen mirroring.

Acknowledgements

- [How to use Miracast to mirror your device's screen wirelessly on your TV—even 4K](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2907520/streaming-media/how-to-use-miracast-to-mirror-your-devices-screen-wirelessly-on-your-tv.html)
- [5.0+ Lollipop - Enable wireless display with Miracast devices](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6/general/5-0-lollipop-enable-wireless-display-t2989544)
- [What Is Miracast? Everything You Need to Know](https://www.tomsguide.com/us/what-is-miracast,review-2284.html)
- [Miracast](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast)

Comment: Did Google give a reason for dropping support for Miracast?

Comment: @Piotr Not that I know of, but I guess promoting the brand, since one can still use miracast even though it is no longer supported officially.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat can you tell more about : what functions need **wireless chipset support**, say hardware upgrade ? encryption or modulation or others ?
As I searched , miracast is built on wifi direct, and direct is a pure software feature .
correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: @user1923105 the actual hardware chipset, you I have already tried this on old devices, and they won't work properly instead show a black screen and wont project the screen so I strongly believe specific hardware is necessary

Comment: Editing build.prop only works with root access on Android 7.0+.

Answer (score 0):

It's a software feature that is only available for some devices. You can still use Quick Connect to cast your screen to TV. For more check out this link http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/skp/faq/1108504

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - well for me and I reckon this is a solution for everyone and dead simple.

Just instal the APP = **Web Video Cast** from the PlayStore.

It seems to project pretty much **everything** to pretty much ANY "smart" ( aka DLNA) device, including MIRACAST, FireStick, ETC ETC ETC...... (even ChromeCast - YUK)

So many millions of folk have their backs against the wall on this, so PLEASE, if it works for you (and I bet it will) PLEASE share it around the other forums.

Comment: Miracast is not even mentioned in the description of that app.